# Is my delivery (Auction) vehicle legitimate of fraudulent mileage scam?

Tags: maintenance, buying

I have 2003 Dodge V6 CV Delivery van . It was from Auction source Postal.
Had bad this and bad that (below)

I have been told by mechanics,that they think the van NO WAY had the reported 32,300K mileage ,and I didn't know it at 1st.
Odometer was taken out at 27.7K miles, and it's very obvious to me now that it was probably 332.2K miles when Auction sold it.
Specific issues with motor vehicle maintenance or repair
had bad (groaning) power steering pump ,and still does
had transmission rebuilt by postal Maintenance people,and a mistake was done leaving it with a bad leak.I had it rebuilt locally.
Air Conditioner was bad worn out whr sold...still bad
radiator leaking lightly then worse replaced
steering wheel worn and driver floor worn through
radio not operative as was back up cam.

Does this sound like a Van that had 32.2K mileage ?

Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

INSTRUMENT CLUSTER was changed out,therefore incorrect as in programmed to reflect false mileage.
FLUID LEAK for transmission was checked and mechanics said something wrong with report of mileage,they replaced fluid and it never stopped leaks until it was
"re-rebuilt" by good mechanic, who noticed it was rebuilt wrongle and torque converter painted.
RADIATOR changed as it was cracked slightly as spout replacement
RADIO stuck of am station with no sound, replacement.
POWER STEERING pump needs replacement.
Attorney sent records that were inconclusive omitting first 10 years ("archived") as they stated it.
Can anyone lend a hand and tell me where to complain about this problem ?
It's a Gen. Service Administration  fleet vehicle , but I doubt the Government people will listen to a person who was victimized by Postal Auction management.

Is a local Police report an option since odometer tampering is a crime ?
Does it constitute odometer fraud when this is done ?

Comment: Sounds like a *Salvage Title* car... If so, depending on the State of purchase, the odometer accuracy doesn't matter.  Also, in some States, there's a checkbox for *Is the odometer correct?* ... if checked *No*, then there's no fraud.

Comment: This is more of a legal question than a maintenance question. You should try asking it over on Law.SE and see what they come up with.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my had around how you thought a 2003 GSA fleet vehicle had only 32 k on it?

Comment: Google your VIN and also check vehiclehistory.com and see if there are any records.